# Powering an RFID Reader + ESP8266 + Servomotor

Tags: batteries, rfid, esp8266

I am looking for the most efficient way to power an ESP8266 along with an Rfid Reader and a servomotor using batteries.

In the past i used 2x18650 batteries in series along with a 3.3V linear regulator(ESP8266 + RFID Reader) and a 6v linear regulator (Servo) but the energy wasted and the bulkiness of two of these batteries made the project i had in mind non-viable.

So is there a way to power all of these components using only one 18650 battery or some other type of battery?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a boost switching regulator to generate the 6 volts from the nominal 3.7 volts of the single battery: -

[image]

This one produces 5 volts but there are plenty of boosters that can be set precisely to the value you need AND produce higher output currents like this one: -

[image]

The resistor feeding the FB pin determines the output voltage. Or there's this one: -

[image]

It can produce 6 volts by adjusting the resistors feeding the FB pin.

You could then use a buck regulator fed from the 6 volt circuit to generate 3.3 volts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andy.This solution looks promising.Would something like this work as the step up regulator? https://goo.gl/tXv78H

Comment: What I have shown is the step up regulator.